# Do we need conntrack for Load Balancer server?

Tags: load-balancing, conntrack, nf-conntrack

I have 3 private dedicated server as Load balancer. And then there is IP Addr Public sign to this private dedicated server.
Suddenly, one of these 3 LB servers got `nf_conntrack: table full, dropping packet`

My dedicated server spec is 32 Core; 256 GB.
I read some nf_conntrack and finally i am planning to increase the conntrack_max to about 4 millions.
But i need a more recommendation from you all who have experience and expert in Server Performance.

When do we need conntrack ? Meanwhile, this is dedicated server with private ip not a NAT gateway.
Should i remove conntrack ?

Answer (score 1):

Linux [netfilter](https://netfilter.org/) has several uses, stateful firewall, NAT and general packet mangling. Stateful firewall is likely to exist in out of the box configurations on not-routers, but it could be something else.

As a host level firewall is useful, and it would be difficult to remove conntrack completely, size it properly so this limit is not hit.

Estimate the total number of flows over 2 minutes. Log application connections, use [conntrack-tools](http://conntrack-tools.netfilter.org/manual.html) or packet capture.  Multiply by some safety ratio to get the order of magnitude necessary.  4 million is a high number, but plausible.  Each consumes a few hundred bytes of memory, but 1 or 2 GB isn't a big deal on a box with a couple hundred GB.

In addition to dropping the new value for `net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_max` in `/etc/sysctl.d/`, resize the nf_conntrack  hashsize. Roughly conntrack max / 4, round up to power of 2.

For some details including for old kernels, see [RHEL KB 8721 ip_conntrack or nf_conntrack : table full, dropping packet](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/8721)

Comment: thanks john, i am studying the docs right now. If you have additional information. I am so glad to give it here.